# Como desabilitar o auto incremento do identificador (id) no Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

Estou trabalhando recentemente com banco não relacional, estou utilizando o Neo4j. Ao gerar os nodes (nós) com os atributos do banco relacional, o Neo4j não permite, pois existe um auto incremento do ID, mas necessito que o atributo ID do banco relacional seja incluso, pois farei as relações com base nessas informações.

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível desativar o auto incremento do ID dos nós no Neo4j. Na verdade, os IDs gerados automaticamente pelo Neo4j são de uso interno do banco de dados. Esses IDs são inclusive reutilizados pelo banco de dados quando um nó ou um relacionamento é excluído, como você pode conferir [neste link](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#get-node-rel-by-id). Desta forma, nós não podemos "confiar" ou depender deste ID.

Nada impede que você crie a sua própria propriedade ID e utilize este ID para fazer suas consultas / atualizações de nós. Por exemplo, ao executar `CREATE (:User {id:1})` você está criando um nó com um label `:User` e uma propriedade id `igual` à 1. Este ID nada tem a ver com o ID interno gerenciado pelo Neo4j, tanto que para acessá-lo em um `WHERE` basta fazer `WHERE node.id = 1`, enquanto que para utilizar o ID interno do Neo4j você precisaria usar a função [ID](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-id) (`WHERE ID(node) = 1`).

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou bastante, fiz igual o recomendado, criei um atributo que referencia o ID do banco relacional, e esta funcionando.

Comment: Legal, @AndreSoares! Por favor, caso esta resposta tenha resolvido seu problema lembre-se de [aceitá-la](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/61007) para informar outros usuários que seu problema foi resolvido e ajudar futuros visualizadores da sua questão. Obrigado! :)